# Why does Dash to Panel keep resetting Action/Click action?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I use `Tweak UI` to edit `Dash to Panel`'s settings.

Under `Tweaks` > `Extensions` > `Dash to Panel` > `Action`, I edit the `Click action` setting to the `Toggle single / Preview multiple` choice.

**Why does this setting reset to the default `Cycle windows+minimize` choice?**

After either the passage of time or some sequence of actions I'm yet to nail down, this setting keeps resetting - very annoying! It appears Tweak UI doesn't update in realtime, so I can't just leave it open/visible to see when the setting changes.